How to interpret output from a MARS model in R?
I am fitting a Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines (MARS) model in R using the package earth. I am fitting a model very like this:
model <- earth(y ~ x, data = df)

And this would have an output that looks something like this:
                   coefficients
(Intercept)        15.4
h(x- -10)          -1.2
h(20 -x)           0.92
h(x -20)           1.01

My problem is how to interpret the coefficients.
At the end, I want to be able to explain what is happening inside each interval (the intervals in this case would be before -10, between -10 and 20, and after 20).
Any help at all would be appreciated.

Visualizing the marginal effect of each predictor will help.  Two ways to do this with MARS:

plotmo::plotmo(fit): This is quick and easy, but difficult to add labels to plots for categorical predictors.
My preferred approach is the pdp R package.  The code will look like this:

p <- pdp::partial(
    object = fit,
    pred.var = <name-of-predictor>,
    rug = TRUE
    );
pdp::plotPartial(p, main = title, rug = TRUE, train = fit$data);

Lastly, I recently gave an introduction to MARS presentation that you might find helpful.  Another great resource is notes on the earth R package.

From this slide, the coefficient for h(x - t) tells you how the average outcome changesd to the right of point t in predictor x.  Similarly, the coefficient for h(t - x) tells you how the average outcome changes to the left of point t in predictor x.

